# Bug of PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ function?

Tags: matrix

The function `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ` is used to decide whether the given matrix is positive semidefinite or not. A matrix $M$ is said to be positive semidefinite if $x^{\dagger}Mx\ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C} ^n$. Here $x^{\dagger}$ means conjugate transpose of the vector $x$. However, the function `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ` in [Mathematica documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ.html#1580952915:%7E:text=A%20matrix%20m%20is%20positive%20semidefinite%20if%20Re%5BConjugate%5Bx%5D.m.x%5D%E2%89%A50%20for%20all%20vectors%20x) seems to only check whether the real part of $x^{\dagger}Mx$ is positive, namely,
$$
\mathrm{Re}\left[ x^{\dagger}Mx \right] \ge 0.
$$
I understand the reason to do this is that the function `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ` works also for numerical value which might cause the imaginary part of $x^{\dagger}Mx$ nonzero. But a better method, in my opinion, is to decide whether the matrix $M$ is Hermitian or not first since a positive semidefinite matrix is [also Hermitian](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveSemidefiniteMatrix.html) and $x^{\dagger}Mx$ is always real for a Hermitian matrix $M$. After thi operation, the problem I just mentioned disappeared.

Furthermore, the current implementation of `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ` will have a bug(I think it's a bug?) that the matrix $\left( \begin{matrix}
    1&      1\\
    0&      1\\
\end{matrix} \right) $ will be recognized to be positive semidefinite.

```
m = ( {
    {1, 1},
    {0, 1}
   } );
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ@m
(*True*)
```

Is my understanding correct, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: In the future, please, refrain from using the `bugs` tag prior to confirmation from other members. This is just a good housekeeping policy :-)

Comment: [The definition on wikipedia is subtly different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix). `m` is a real matrix so you don't check it's Hermitian. It _is_ positive semidefinite. All it's eigenvalues are greater than or equal to zero. `Eigenvalues[m]` is `{1,1}`, or equivalently `Solve[Det[m - λ IdentityMatrix[2]] == 0, λ]` gives `{{λ -> 1}, {λ -> 1}}` . A matrix that is Positive Definite is also Positive Semidefinite. There are no solutions in: `FindInstance[ConjugateTranspose[x] . m . x < 0,  x ∈ Vectors[2]]`.

Comment: [But this section on consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Consistency_between_real_and_complex_definitions) between complex/real definitions says since every real matrix is a complex matrix, the two must agree. Since `m` is not Hermitian, it is only Positive definite in the Real sense. I think you'd have to do `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[m] && HermitianMatrixQ[m]` if you wanted it like that. This seems to be an implementation choice by Wolfram, as a lot of the time in optimization problems you are not dealing with complex matrices.